# ¿Cómo hacer referencia desde CSS a un elemento con estilos inline?

Tags: html, css

Tengo la necesidad de editar un `div` **que no tiene clase**, y **sus padres tampoco tienen clase**, así que no puedo identificarlo de la forma habitual, sus estilos están cargados por element style (estilos directos) lo que pude detectar es que ese `div` es el único que tiene una propiedad en particular (`div style="cursor: default"`), así que intenté poner en el css:

```
div[style="cursor: default"]
```

Pero no me sirve, solo me detecta si escribo `div[style]`, pero esto causa que edita todos los `divs` con element style, alguien sabe como puedo hacer ese llamado de manera ideal?

Comment: puedes adicionar el código de html de la estructura que tienes de los divs.

Comment: Compartenos el html de tu proyecto, para poder darte una solución, porque por lo pronto con esa poca información, no hay forma.

Comment: Debería funcionar si has puesto los espacios y todo igual: https://jsfiddle.net/2t7wfgcu/3/

Comment: Podrías agregarle id a cada uno de los divs, y editar utilizando el id como referencia

Comment: Podrías probar con este selector `div[style^="cursor"]`, con ello estarías seleccionando todos los divs que tengan la etiqueta style y como primera palabra cursor. Aunque de igual manera serviría un ejemplo del html para ser mas certeros

Comment: El código es una API, por ello se me complica editar y agregar un id o clase específico porque está construido con divs que tienen sus estilos directos, no en hoja de estilo

Comment: Accede a dicho div (y cualquier elemento) mediante el [DOM](https://www.w3.org/2005/03/DOM3Core-es/introduccion.html) analizando la estructura particular del sitio.

Comment: Hay texto único en ese div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya que no muestras tu HTML, puedo suponer que en ese elemento tienes algún estilo más, y por eso no es una coincidencia exacta (`=`) o que no tengas exactamente el estilo tal y como está implementado en el HTML (mira mi segundo ejemplo).

Como solo tienes un `div` que contenga dicho estilo, podrías utilizar los selectores de atributo, en este caso `*=` con el que obtienes los elementos que contienen el valor en cuestión.

```css
div[style*="cursor: default"]{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div style="cursor: default"></div>
```

**NOTA:** Tienes que tener mucho cuidado ya que lo tienes que poner exactamente como esté en tu elemento ya que de lo contrario no te encontrará el elemento (p. ej: poner/quitar un espacio en el selector haría que no funcionara).

```css
div[style*="cursor:default"]{ /*Nota que no hay espacio entre cursor y default */
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div style="cursor: default"></div>
```